# How do I use a periodic trigger in Automagic?

Tags: automation

There's an app called [Automagic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.gridvision.ppam.androidautomagic) which uses flow charts to create workflows that let you perform custom sequences of actions on your Android (essentially macros, but with an advanced interface for editing them).

**Can somebody please explain how to use the periodic trigger?**

I've tried using it to kick start a flow, but it never fires. I've ensured that the flow is enabled, I've checked the logs and there's nothing about any problems occurring with launching the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of this writing, there are apparently issues with the Periodic Timer trigger. (According to [this forum post](http://automagic4android.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1739)) Using the Period Timer (Inexact) trigger instead works, but is still not very consistent. (Which, yes, I realize is not to be expected since "Inexact" is in the title of the trigger)

Answer (score 0):

You must enter the time. For example, if you want it to be every 5 seconds you need to write "5s".

Comment: Thank you, but I've obviously figured that one out. That much is apparent right in the interface and the help files that come with the App.